# :first-letter not working with strong

Tags: html, css

I give up. Why is :first-letter not working here?

```
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
strong:first-letter {
  color: red;
}

<strong>test test</strong>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Further to other answers, it also (in Chromium at least) works with elements with `display: inline-block`, so the `display` simply has to be anything other than `inline` (including [`list-item`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cCdWK/2/)), for example:

```
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
strong::first-letter {
    color: red;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cCdWK/1/).

Also, `::first-letter` is a pseudo-element, so the syntax should be double-colon rather than single, in order to distinguish the selector from a pseudo-class.

Comment: It works! Great addution. And I verified it works in IE10 as well.

Comment: `::first-letter` will work on any element that contains an inline formatting context. If an element participates in an inline formatting context without creating one itself, `::first-letter` will never apply. That leaves you with anything except `display: inline` and `display: none`. Also note that you can keep single colons for certain pseudo-elements if you require old IE compatibility, otherwise it's good practice to use double colons.

Answer (score 5):

`first-letter` does not work with inline elements, only on block elements.

Answer (score 2):

`first-letter` can only be used with block elements.

This will work, but the question is how useful a block level `strong` is:

http://jsfiddle.net/UZpLG/

```
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
  display: block;
}
strong:first-letter {
  color: red;
}


<strong>test test</strong>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/afoyon/1/edit)

**:first-letter** does not work with inline elements

Modify your CSS with this one, add **display:block** in your **strong{...}**

```
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
  display: block;
}
strong:first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [Note: The "first-letter" selector can only be used with block-level elements.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp)

and [Block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements)

and example http://jsfiddle.net/eLvWt/6/

```
strong {
    display:block;
    color:green;
}

strong:first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

NOTICED: Please ignore this my answer's references since it is out-dated.

Comment: While it may be correct in this instance, w3schools is a terrible resource to use as a reference because it is often wrong.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - Actually w3schools is wrong again. Elements that have `display:inline-block` are inline-level elements, but `:first-letter` works with it. The important factor is that it creates a *block box* which has a stack of line boxes, so there exists a first letter of a first line, which can be styled accordingly.

Comment: Thanks of your information. I will update my answer to notice about that